# Is there a way to force a router-view component reload within the same route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using nested vue-router views to display pages of content, with `<transition>` showing that changes did happen. Currently it works with page changes, but I also have filters that change displayed content when they are applied, and since applying them doesn't necessarily change the page, Vue doesn't reload the component, which doesn't apply the transition and doesn't refresh some data. So basically what I need is a way to force a "refresh" without changing the url.

At the moment I'm using the `:key="$route.fullPath"` property on `<router-view>` element which works with changing url, but not with refreshes. I was able to simulate the required behaviour by using an external variable and adding it to the key like `:key="$route.fullPath + pageKey"` and incrementing it before each forced refresh, but I feel this solution is unclean and unintuitive.

What I currently have is:

```
<template>
    <section>

        ...

        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
            <router-view :key="$route.fullPath + pageKey"></router-view>
        </transition>

        ...

    </section>
</template>
```

And each forced refresh is basically this:

```
++this.pageKey;
this.$router.push('/1');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reload the view when `this.pageKey` changes, it is probably because you load the data in your `created()` or `mounted()` lifecycle handler. Your solution is a possibility, and probably the only real possibility if you require the transition to play on a change of `this.pageKey`.

Otherwise, consider moving your logic of loading data to a method, and load it in an immediately invoked watcher on `this.pageKey`. This means it loads on startup, and also loads when the pageKey has been changed.

```
computed: {
  // Vuex if you use it, or some other way of storing the pageKey
  ...mapGetters('pageKey')
},

watch: {
  pageKey: {
    immediate: true,
    handler () {
      this.loadData();
    }
  }
},

methods: {
  loadData() {
    // noop
  }
}
```

---

If you want to eliminate `pageKey` at all, one way to do it is by simply calling `loadData` in the click handler of the refresh button, or emitting an event. If the component containing the button and the component handling loading of data are not positioned nicely for a traditional event, you can always create an event bus and listen for it that way:

```
// main.js
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();
```

```
// MyComponent.vue
created() {
  this.$bus.$on('force-refresh', this.loadData);
},

beforeDestroy() {
  // Prevent memory leaks
  this.$bus.$off('force-refresh', this.loadData);
},

methods: {
  loadData() {
    // noop
  }
}
```

```
// MyButton.vue
<template>
  <button @click="forceRefresh">I want all the new data</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    forceRefresh() {
      this.$bus.$emit('force-refresh');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I was actually wondering if I could do a refresh/reload without using an extra variable. Reloading data seems to work for my solution when applying filters, but transition doesn't play and it just came to my mind that a way to force trigger a transition would also solve my problem. Other than that I am actually doing what you've suggested :)

Comment: I have edited my answer with events, which would solve the problem without a counter

Comment: I don't see how this helps the transition to be honest